# Registration using sfGuardDoctrine plugin

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I am building a job searching website using symfony. The site will have registration, login and user profile. 
I found sfGuardDoctrine plugin and trying to integrate it with my project.

Am I on the right track? or is there any other plugins available to integrate the above function with doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

It is the best choice to manage user.

Then you have 2 others goods plugins to improve sfGuard:

- "Provides an additional table that stores information everytime an sfGuardUser logs in.": http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardLoginHistoryPlugin
- "Allows users of a site protected by sfDoctrineGuardPlugin to create new accounts, verifying them by email. Both account creation and password changes require email verification as a speed bump to slow down spammers.": https://github.com/fizyk/sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Can i create jobseeker as a module or do I have to create it as an new app. 

all:
  .settings:
    enabled_modules:      [default, sfGuardAuth]
    login_module:           sfGuardAuth
    login_action:           signin
the above yml add the auth for all modules, how can I add it to a single module.